# How to extract and make use of the file name in R

Tags: r

I have a bunch of files whose name represents the date on which it was created. Eg: 10-02-2017.csv, 17-02-2017.csv etc.

For all the files that I have (approx. 60) I want to add an extra column which is equal to the date in the name of the file. Eg:

- If the file name is 10-02-2017.csv, I want to add a column titled "date" where each entry is equal to 10-02-2017
- If the file name is 17-02-2017.csv, I want to add a column titled "date" where each entry is equal to 10-02-2017

and so on. Could someone please guide me on how this can be done in R?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before posting a question you should check if a similar question has been answered before. If you don't find a helpful answer, please show in your question what you have tried so far and where you have been stuck.

Comment: `?list.files` will give you a list of files in a given path and with a given pattern. Next, you can read them through `?read.table` and similar, add the column and write them back with `?write.table`.

Answer (score 1):

`list.files` is your friend. It has an argument (`full.names`, see `?list.files`) to retain or not the entire path. I guess you will need so set it to `FALSE`.

Then you just need to remove `.csv` from your filenames and turn it into a `data.frame`:

```
# lf <- list.files(your_path, full.names=FALSE) # what you should do by your side
lf <- c("10-02-2017.csv", "17-02-2017.csv") # to simulate a `list.files`
data.frame(date=gsub(".csv", "", lf)) 
date
1 10-02-2017
2 17-02-2017
```

You could also `your_df$date <- gsub(".csv", "", lf)` if you already have a `data.frame` with variables of interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot (y). Works